# Calendar set date causing exception with message "Unparsable date"

Tags: java, simpledateformat, datetime-parsing, java.util.calendar, unparseable

My code to get the calendar date frone the string  "2018-04-14'T'15:38:14",
it is currently causing a exception WHEN i call `setTime`.  The code

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    // format of date yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd 'T' 
    cal.setTime(sdf.parse("2018-04-14'T'15:38:14"));// all done1
```

The above line causes a exception saying "Unparsable date"

Comment: this doesnt compile. you seem to have some code missing from your question

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Stacktrace, please? It would show you that the exception doesn’t come from `setTime`, but from `parse`.

Comment: Don’t tell me there are apostrophes in the string you need to parse? Surely it’s `2018-04-14T15:38:14`, not `2018-04-14'T'15:38:14`??

Answer (score 1):

'T' is a constant. Notice the subtle difference. The format is defined with T in single quotes but when you pass the value, it's without.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
// format of date yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
cal.setTime(sdf.parse("2018-04-14T15:38:14"));// all done1
```

Comment: and there are some whitespaces in OP's format that you removed that *might* have caused issues as well